# Copy data in template form and select option is not displaying data angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I need to build a function to copy data in a table. The idea is when select a row and click the copy button, the selected row will be copied. I was able to copy data in component, and pushed it to the array list, the input fields worked fine. But the select fields didn't display data.I am new to Angular 2, any help is appreciated.
Here is my code, it is a very complicated table.

```
   <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"                  
           (click)="copySelectedService()">Copy Service</button>

   <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" id="service">
      <tr *ngFor="let s of serviceList  let i = index">
       <td>
         <div>
         <select class="custom-select service" [ngModel]="s?.srvc_nm" 
           name="srvc_nm{{i}}" (ngModelChange)="s?.srvc_nm?
               s.prog_srvc_nm=$event:null">
                    <option></option>
                    <option *ngFor="let a of dropdownLists['srvc']" 
                       [ngValue]="a.description" >{{a.description}}</option>
         </select>
        </div>
         <div class="cell top-cell">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="channel_nb{{i}}" 
               [ngModel]="s?.channel_nb" (ngModelChange)="s?.channel_nb? 
               .channel_nb=$event:null">
         </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
```

Component.ts

```
    serviceList: any[];

    copySelectedService() {
       const cloned = Object.assign({}, this.serviceList[this.index]);    
       this.serviceList.push(cloned);
    }
```

Service model:

```
        export class Service {
           srvc_nm?: string;
           channel_nb?: string;
             ....

           constructor () {
              this.prog_srvc_nm = '';
              this.channel_nb = '';
           ....
          }
        }
```

Did I do something wrong with select option?

Comment: Whats the value in `this.index` inside your function `copySelectedService `?

Comment: it is the row I selected to copy from, this.index = i, the serviceList index.